# Solving Uncaught ReflectionException: Class log does not exist in C:\......\Container.php:

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am experiencing an unexpected Reflection Exception error that `class log does not exist`. I am currently using Laravel 5.2. The addition of use `log` amongst namespaces into my controller hasn't solved this.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class log does not exist in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:741 

Stack trace:

#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(741): ReflectionClass->__construct('log')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(631): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('log', Array) 
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(674): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('log', Array) 
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(842): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('log') 
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(805): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter)) 
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(775): Illuminate\Conta in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 741
```

controller.php

```
  <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Log;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesResources;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;

 class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests,AuthorizesResources, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}
```

routes.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Comment: Show your routes and controller code

Comment: Have you tried `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: yah but still stuck on the same error

Comment: did you try `php artisan clear-compiled'? is that a fresh install? if so, did you check the folder permissions?

Comment: Do you have this problem in a unit test?

Comment: I think you have a problem with creating application.

Answer (score 1):

Check for spaces in your .env or config files as suggested here

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/class-log-does-not-exist?page=2

enclose it with double quotes if any

Comment: There are no spaces in my .env file

Comment: Did you try enclosing the values of your .env variables with double quotes

Comment: yah and there is still no change